# Could not Find Implicit parameter in scala typeclass

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a type class based on the type data to load --

Here are the types:

```
trait DataSource
case class HDFSSource(path: String) extends DataSource
case class HiveTableSource(db: String, tbl: String) extends DataSource
```

here is the trait

```
trait Loader[A, B, C] {
  //Any Spark loader requires
  // A -> Input Type
  // B -> Output Type
  // C -> some type of implicit context provided by the compiler from the sourounding environemnt..
  def load(input: A)(implicit context: C): B
```

And here is the implementation:

```
object Loader {
  implicit object HiveLoader extends Loader[HiveTableSource, DataFrame, HiveContext] {
    def load(source: HiveTableSource)(implicit hc: HiveContext): DataFrame = {
      val db = source.db
      val tbl = source.tbl
      val df =  hc.sql(s"select * from $db.$tbl")
      df
    }
  }
  def loadDataSource[A: Loader, B, C](d: A) = implicitly[Loader[A,B,C]].load(d)
```

The compiler complains that it can not find implicit evidence for parameter, specificly in the "implicitly[A.B.C]:

The goal is to have a typeclass that has different behavior for each type, and also use a different context (implicitly provided by the environment)

Answer (score 4):

```scala
def loadDataSource[A, B, C](d: A)(implicit ldr: Loader[A,B,C], context: C): B = ldr.load(d)
```

I did not try compiling it myself but I'm fairly sure that would work.

`loadDataSource[A: Loader, B, C](d: A)` is desugared to `loadDataSource[A, B, C](d: A)(implicit ev: Loader[A])`, which doesn't work here because Loader takes 3 type parameters. So you have to explicitly annotate the implicit parameter instead of using a context bound.

In order to call Loader's `load` method, an implicit C must be provided. That's why I added the additional `context: C` implicit parameter.

Comment: import Loader._

    loadDataSource(c.src) 

results in "Could not find implicit value for paramater ldr. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to type annotate loadDataSource

So `import Loader._; loadDataSource[HiveTableSource, DataFrame, HiveContext](c.src)` would work I believe.